# exec "tail -f xxx" with rust

Tags: rust, command, tail

I want to exec `tail -f a` with rust, but there is no output when I run following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    // "a" is a text file and some characters have been written to it
    let child = Command::new("tail").args(&["-f", "a"])
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn().expect("failed tail command");
    let mut s = String::new();
    child.stdout.expect("error of stdout")
        .read_to_string(&mut s).expect("error of read all");
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

When I append a new line to file `a` I just get `tail: a: file truncated`.

Comment: In addition to what John wrote in his answer, please note that the output of `tail` indicates that you likely used `echo ... >a` rather than `echo ... >>a`, so instead of _appending_ a line to the file, you _replaced_ all existing content with the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_to_string` reads until EOF, which will never be hit since `tail` outputs continuously and never ends. Change your program to read and print a line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer mentions to read one line at a time. Here I show you how:

run with: `$ cargo test -- --nocapture`

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::io::BufRead;
    use std::io::BufReader;
    use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
    #[test]
    fn test_stdout() {
        let cmd = Command::new("./slow_output_stream")
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn()
            .expect("command failed");
        let mut out = cmd.stdout.unwrap();
        let mut reader = BufReader::new(&mut out);

        loop {
            let mut line = String::new();
            let num_bytes = reader.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
            if num_bytes == 0 {
                println!("End of stream.");
                break;
            }
            println!("The line: {:?}", line);
        }
        println!("Done.");
    }
}
```

Extra credit, here is a slow output stream in Rust, just build it and copy the binary where the other program can find it:

```rust
use std::{thread, time};

fn print_row(row: &Vec<i32>) -> () {
    let wait_time = time::Duration::from_secs(2);

    row.iter().for_each(|int| {
        println!("{}", int);
        thread::sleep(wait_time);
    });
}

fn main() {
    let matrix = vec![vec![1, 2, 3], vec![4, 5, 6], vec![7, 8, 9]];

    matrix.iter().for_each(print_row);
}
```